# Await in C# for an event in C++ - as a task or a wait handle

Tags: c#, c++, .net, asynchronous, lmdb

I program mostly in  .NET and I love its async/concurrency primitives such as Tasks, ResetEvents, etc. Today for the first time I made meaningful changes to a C++ program and understood how the whole build process works (I [updated](https://github.com/buybackoff/LMDB.NET) LigthningDB.NET project to 0.9.14). But I still lack C++ knowledge.

One new feature that I want to add to the LMDB project (for my own needs) is a notification system (similar to Redis):

- I want a cursor returning an awaitable object that will signal on every data change in its table.
- I want to get some data together with the signal (a pointer to a data structure), e.g. key or key + value.
- This object will be disposed together with the cursor and is a part of the cursor, but it signals on changes in a DB for which the cursor has a reference.
- This must work cross platform some day (or some year). I am OK with any dirty Windows-specific hacks if they do the job.

Typical use case is a writer and N readers waiting for new messages. This will allow IPC and fast persistence 2-in-1. LMDB supports concurrent reading from different processes (while Esent and LevelDB do not).

`System.Threading` primitives are available from C++ and I understand how to use WaitHandle for a blocking call. Is there a way to make this async? There is a [great series of articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266983.aspx) about async synchronization primitives, but they use `TaskCompletionSource` and that works only inside .NET. Is it possible to make a similar solution for native interop?

One solution could be named pipes or socket translating changes to one listener/dispatcher (Redis or [Rhino.Queues](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-queues) style), but performance will suffer: writes will have to allocate, copy and push data and data will have to travel - much worse than passing a pointer to a data structure that is already in memory.

Another option is to move the listening cursor to the key and send a signal. After the signal a C# listener will know that the cursor has values at the updated key. This kinf of solves data transfer part, but with WaitHandles it is blocking - in my use case blocking is worse than the sockets [allocation/copy/delay] combination.

Are there better options?

Additional questions:

1. Am I reinventing a bicycle here?
2. Could you please point to open source libraries where .NET program awaits (non-blocking) for a C/C++ signal (if they exist)?
3. Should I use LMDB for that workflow? Windows in my priority and I have had very bad time trying to make LevelDB work at all (stopped trying). Are there better alternatives for everything LMDB does + signalling?

**Update**

I have found [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#WaitHandles) this method:

```
public static Task WaitOneAsync(this WaitHandle waitHandle)
{
    if (waitHandle == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("waitHandle");

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    var rwh = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(waitHandle, 
        delegate { tcs.TrySetResult(true); }, null, -1, true);
    var t = tcs.Task;
    t.ContinueWith(_ => rwh.Unregister(null));
    return t;
}
```

The [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9f75h7a(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) for `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` says that:

> The wait operation is performed by a **thread** from the thread pool. The
>   delegate is executed by a worker **thread** when the object's state
>   becomes signaled or the time-out interval elapses.
>   ...
>   The **wait thread** uses the Win32 **WaitForMultipleObjects** function to monitor registered wait operations.

Am I correct that these are two different threads, and the first wait thread is the only one that will block if there are no signals?

Comment: I am afraid that the solution was 5 additional minutes of googling away, while writing this took much more. Still want to know if this is THE solution? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#WaitHandles

Comment: I don't know much about the efficiency of `RegisterWaitForSingleObject`. I suspect it is IO completion port based and therefore quite efficient. I don't think there is a thread dedicated to waiting on that handle.; Consider making the other process send you a 1 byte named pipe message (a dummy). You can then use NamedPipeStream.ReadAsync to wait fully asynchronously.

Comment: Also note that asynchronous waiting is usually *more* CPU intensive and has higher latency. Maybe the whole question is moot because of this.

Comment: I have very big number of waiters, definitely hundreds or more. I cannot afford blocking. But one of the key features of LMDB is that it owns data, so passing a pointer to data and reading memory from it never allocates or copies data. That is the low hanging fruit I am trying to reach

Comment: Could I pass a pointer as PtrInt via a pipe/socket? That way I could use the pointer address received from pipe/socket and access memory via the address. How to ensure that the address is fixed? LMDB uses fixed memory maps, as I understand - is this enough guarantee that a pointer will work?

Comment: Also, writing to pipe/socket could slow down the DB writer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RWFSO uses special thread pool threads to wait for multiple handles. There's a built-in limit of 63 handles per thread, so this is not as efficient as IOCPs. I wouldn't recommend a handle-based solution even though MREs *can* be used to solve this (MREs can be used to solve pretty much everything...).

C++ does not have a notion of "events". The traditional approach is to take a callback function pointer (which, combined with [`Boost.Bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/bind/bind.html) and [`Boost.Function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/function.html) is not nearly as painful these days). A more modern approach would be [`Boost.Signals2`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/signals2.html).

Comment: And the callback can play well with the Task async pattern by calling `TaskCompletionSource`'s `SetResult` method

Comment: @Stephen Is it feasible to send IntPtr via a pipe or socket and then access data directly by that address? Currently I use both pipe and socket in different solutions to transfer actual data, so I will hugely win if I could just pass a pointer to all subscribers. I could implement an event that will trigger on address arrival, and N interested parties could subscribe to event and do whatever they want. Is this a sane design?

Comment: I believe he is trying to raise an event across processes. There is a database process and a client process to be notified.

Comment: usr: I agree. @V.B.: Pointers don't work across processes. The same pointer value means different things to different processes because of address space virtualization.

Comment: There is an option to use fixed memory map or I could use offsets from zero, but this smells. I am thinking about a named semaphore and a queue of keys/value pointers on C side. In append-only mode even the queue is not needed, only the number of new unseen values. Also I could make some dispatching scheme and reduce number of waiting threads. 63 is a good number, thank you for the info!

Comment: @StephenCleary BTW, thank you for all your blog posts and other info on the web and GitHub. I have learned a lot from you even before this answer :) (last question: is there an example of a similar pure C solution, not C++/Boost?)

Comment: @V.B.: The standard way of doing this in C is using function pointers with a "state" parameter that's passed along. E.g., `void (*callback)(void *)`

Answer (score 0):

Update: There was a logical flaw: to use a C callback, there must be a single C process and several C# processes. But with MMF, only memory is shared B/W 2 different C processes. So I either need a C server like Redis (but we already have Redis!) or inter-process signaling.

I had experience with [reliable synchronization and Redis](https://github.com/buybackoff/Ractor.CLR/blob/master/src/Ractor/Actor.fs) and that was the root of the question - I wanted to have a similar solution but for local machine with persistence.

Probably rewriting the Redis logic with named MREs/AREs is the simplest approach. As Stephen said, MRE could do anything.

---

(any votes should go to the answer by Stephen Cleary, here is just an example)

The answer is to use TaskCompletionSource and a Callback to set its result.

Example of a callback:

C#:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
delegate int CompareCallback(int a, int b);

[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
class NativeMethod
{

    [DllImport("CppDynamicLinkLibrary.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int CompareInts(int a, int b, CompareCallback cmpFunc);

}
```

C:

```
// Type-definition: 'PFN_COMPARE' now can be used as type
typedef int (CALLBACK *PFN_COMPARE)(int, int);

// An exported/imported stdcall function using a DEF file
// It requires a callback function as one of the arguments
int __stdcall CompareInts(int a, int b, PFN_COMPARE cmpFunc)
{
    // Make the callback to the comparison function

    // If a is greater than b, return a; 
    // If b is greater than or equal to a, return b.
    return ((*cmpFunc)(a, b) > 0) ? a : b;
}
```

sample code: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSPInvokeDll-b05779d0

Comment: You should always typedef the actual object, not (just) a pointer to the object. That allows you to use the typedef for the actual object declarations as well. e.g.
  `typedef int (CALLBACK PFN_COMPARE)(int, int);

int __stdcall CompareInts(int a, int b, PFN_COMPARE *cmpFunc)`